# Gadgeteer voltage sensor that can measure up to 8000 volts?

Tags: voltage

I am a software engineer by day and a pig farmer the rest of the time.  I am looking at automating many of the mundane tasks around the farm by deploying IoT all around my farm.  One of the first tasks is to gather the current voltage of my many hot lines scattered about the farm.  The most powerful shock might be in the 8k volt range.

Is anyone aware of a ready made voltage sensor that could be wired into a Gadgeteer solution?

If not, how might I accomplish monitoring voltage this high in a manner that I could wire into a Gadgeteer solution?

**Update**

*What is Gadgeteer:*

This is a set of modules that can easily be plugged together to create something interesting.  You can then deploy C# code to it via USB and quickly get a working thing up and running.  In the case where a readily available module is not available you can use a bread board and wire in any other readily available circuit/sensor that is on the market.  This tool set allows software developers to dabble in the hardware world.

*What is a Hotline:*

In this case I run a pig farm (among other animals to be managed).  I keep the pigs in a paddock by surrounding it with a set of steel wires that is not directly grounded to anything.  A pulse is fired from a (solar in this case) electric charge box every X seconds.  The pulse without any interference for up to 30 miles worth of wire tops out at 8000 volts.  When the animal touches the wire...and the ground...they get a good zap to teach them to step back.  I have touched it a few times as have my kids...and it is a GOOD ZAP.  I have basically this model charger: http://www.tractorsupply.com/en/store/zarebareg%3B-30-mile-solar-low-impedance-fence-charger

*Do I need to measure for the exact voltage?*

No - not really.  I need to mostly establish a baseline.  So if the 8k voltage was some other numeric value that I could establish as a baseline to be measured every hour or so that would be good enough.  I need mostly to be able to collect data and then reason over it.  If a fence was down I could pretty quickly get a notification for being way below allowable tolerances.  But in the case that weeds grow up all around the fence the number of plant contacts over time would slowly but significantly impact the effectiveness of the fence.  So baseline plus semi-accurate deviation would be good enough.

Comment: gadgeteer I am assuming means hobbyist? 8kV sounds pretty hectic, but i'm assuming you can tap off an isolated transformer down to 80V for example, and use voltage dividers and/or rectifier circuits to get a DC voltage reading for "RMS" voltage on that line

Comment: Can you explain what a "hot line" is? Is it imperative that you measure the exact voltage on it or just that it has _some_ voltage on it (is not dead / faulty)?

Comment: Are you looking to set up some sort of electric fence monitoring system - are those the 8kV hot lines?

Comment: All questions should be answered!  Let me know if there are any more questions.

Comment: [.NET Gadgeteer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Gadgeteer)

Comment: You basically want a high voltage probe.  Conceptually a resistive divider made of high value resistors, then feeding into a handy high-impedance low voltage measurement device such as a scope, FET meter, or ADC (possibly with buffer amp in front of it).  Safety is in the implementation details.

Answer (score 2):

Measured *inside* the fence-charger case?  Or you want hv probes out in the rain?

Easiest is to just buy a high-voltage probe for a voltmeter.  These are just a thousands-megs resistor in a heavy insulator.  Hook a 10meg resistor across your A/D inp, then put the HV probe between the A/D-inp and fence wire.  A/D-common goes to earth.  That reduces 8kv pulses to perhaps 8v or 0.8v.  For added safety, perhaps put a chain of several 1meg resistors in series with that wire from A/D to earth.  With the impedances you're dealing with, a chain of 1meg resistors is a good conductor.

But if lightning sometimes kills your fence charger, you're asking it to come in and zap your A/D block, or worse.

Answer (score 1):

I like the idea of remotely monitoring the fence. I live on a horse farm and also use electric fencing that needs to be checked periodically for shorts against the steel poles.

You can tie a neon bulb between the hot wire and ground to get a periodic flash when the charger pulses. Use a phototransistor/photodiode to detect the flash and you now have a high-isolation optocoupler that your gadgeteer can  read.

You probably need to use a neon bulb close to the fence rating, otherwise it will clamp the voltage to a lower value and lose its effectiveness for animal control purposes.

Most fence chargers have a light that flashes when the fence pulses. If there is a dead short, then it won't flash (although you'll hear the relay click). If yours does this, you can use the same photodetector technique above to monitor it.

Now add a couple of RF communication modules (I have some Digi units around here somewhere...) and you can monitor the fence from the comfort of your house.